# How do I link to the pages of an artefact produced by gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

GitLab jobs can produce [artefacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts). Artefacts are produced by specific runs (unique id `job_id` and are associated to a jobs name `job_name` (defined in the project's `.gitlab-ci.yml`) and a ref (e.g. branch). A `(ref, job_name)` can have multiple `job_id`, but typically the relevant one is the most recent one.

For an artefact `htmlcov/index.html` produced by the job `%{job_id}`, its respective `page` is given by the URL

`https://%{namespace}.gitlab.io/-/%{project_name}/-/jobs/%{job_id}/artifacts/htmlcov/index.html`

As per link above, I know that I can browse the artefact using the URL

`https://gitlab.com/%{namespace}/%{project_name}/-/jobs/artifacts/%{ref}/browse?job=%{job_name}`

#### Question

Given a `%{ref}` and a `%{job_name}`, What is the URL of the artefact produced by the latest `%{job_id}`?

I am unable to construct the URL for the pages (typically starting with `https://%{namespace}.gitlab.io`. I tried different variations of

`https://%{namespace}.gitlab.io/-/%{project_name}/-/jobs/%{job_id}/artifacts/htmlcov/index.html`

such as

`https://%{namespace}.gitlab.io/-/%{project_name}/-/jobs/%{ref}/artifacts/htmlcov/index.html?job=%{job_name}`

but all lead to 404. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an existing but undocumented feature. Use

```
https://gitlab.com/%{namespace}/%{project_name}/-/jobs/artifacts/%{ref}/file/%{path}?job=%{job_name}
```

for example,

```
https://gitlab.com/jorgecarleitao/schemaflow/-/jobs/artifacts/master/file/htmlcov/index.html?job=coverage
```

[There is now an Merge Request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/21890) to add this to gitlab's documentation.