# GitLab open HTML from artifact in new tab instead of downloading it

Tags: gitlab, artifact

I have a pylint GitLab CI job that is producing successfully a a badge and an HTML report under a pylint folder.

The resulting URLs are

https://gitlab.com/GROUP/PROJECT/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/pylint/pylint.svg?job=pylint

for the badge and

https://gitlab.com/GROUP/PROJECT/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/pylint/index.html?job=pylint

for the HTML report.

The badge is shown correctly, but the link *downloads* the HTML instead of opening it in a new tab.

This happens in multiple places: the main page of the repo (under the title of the project), the README which is markdown, and the docs which are in RST format.

How can I write the URL to open the HTML in a new tab?

I am using [pylint-gitlab](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-gitlab/) to create the HTML report, but the instructions there made use of the *public* folder which messed up the deployment of my documentation to GitLab pages, so I reverted to the solution shown in [this SO post (2019 update)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47342642/10401171).

```
pylint:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pip install pylint-gitlab pylint-exit anybadge
    - mkdir pylint
    - pylint --output-format=text pyswgo | tee pylint/pylint.log || pylint-exit $?
    - PYLINT_SCORE=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' pylint/pylint.log)
    - pylint --exit-zero --output-format=pylint_gitlab.GitlabCodeClimateReporter pyswgo > codeclimate.json
    - pylint --exit-zero --output-format=pylint_gitlab.GitlabPagesHtmlReporter pyswgo > pylint/index.html
    - anybadge --label=Pylint --file=pylint/pylint.svg --value=$PYLINT_SCORE 2=red 4=orange 8=yellow 10=green
    - echo "Pylint score is $PYLINT_SCORE"
  artifacts:
    expose_as: "Pylint artifacts"
    paths:
      - pylint
    reports:
      codequality: codeclimate.json
    when: always
```

Comment: Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52463777/how-do-i-link-to-the-pages-of-an-artefact-produced-by-gitlab) I tested https://gitlab.com/GROUP/PROJECT/-/jobs/artifacts/master/file/pylint/index.html?job=pylint and it seems to point me to the artifacts of the latest job but with an annoying redirection stating "You are being redirected away from GitLab
This page is hosted on GitLab pages but contains user-generated content and may contain malicious code. Do not accept unless you trust the author and source."

Any way I can jump this step and show directly the HTML file?